# GitHub: using pictures in README.md

Tags: image, github

I'm just wondering how AdEven added pictures to the README.md hosted on GitHub without having the pictures in the repo (you can find their GitHub-project here: https://github.com/adeven/adjust_ios_sdk).

The images are hosted under https://raw.github.com/adeven/adjust_sdk/master/Resources/ios/.png and I want to know how to upload the pictures exactly like AdEven.

Thanks and Regards,
Sascha

Comment: tried clicking the file and pressing the `Raw` button yet? It's the same markup notation that stackoverflow uses btw. Which is known as [Markdown](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown)

Comment: The images are in another repository on github: https://github.com/adeven/adjust_sdk/tree/master/Resources/ios

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77319849/4393351

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you look at the raw version of the file  (https://raw.github.com/adeven/adjust_ios_sdk/master/README.md)

You can see how they do it.

`![][drag]` where you want the picture

`[drag]: https://raw.github.com/adeven/adjust_sdk/master/Resources/ios/drag2.png`

To define the file location.

Just replace the name and the location with your own.   The `raw` url is direct access into the repo, so GH doesn't apply any formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem by going to github, in to my repo then creating and issue. In the text box inser the picture you would like to have in your readme.md. When you insert it in the text box it will give you the URL to your image. Simply copy the image url that it provided and insert it to your readme!