# How to display an image in readme file on Github?

Tags: github

I'm trying to display an image on my `readme.md` file on my git repo. I've done this before in my other repos, but for some reason this doesn't work this time.

Currently my code produces the following in the `readme` file:

[image]

I tried:

```
![Model](path_to_img.pdf)
```

Which just makes the link open the folder where the image is and show it

I also tried

```
![Model](link_address_to_image)
```

Which does the same thing.

I also tried

```
![Model](path_to_img.pdf?raw=true)
```

Which makes the link download the image

Comment: Your link is likely wrong because you need to specify link to raw image. make sure that link works in your browser outside github by copy\pasting it into address bar, web browser should display the image only and nothing else, if yes that's the link for markdown.

Comment: Links work just fine

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That display means you aren't linking to the file path. Unfortunately github is really finicky about how it loads images in readme's and you have to use their domain specifically for serving static content. If your image is part of your repo you need to access the file via the `raw.githubusercontent.com` subdomain specifically the pattern is `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<username>/<repo name>/<branch>/<path to file>`.

For example on [this project](https://github.com/Descent098/ezcv) since the homepage image is in `./.github/logo.png` and on the master branch of https://github.com/Descent098/ezcv I had to do:

```markdown
![ezcv logo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Descent098/ezcv/master/.github/logo.png)
```

### Edit

Looking at your post I just noticed you have a `.pdf` file not a `.png`. PDF's can't be loaded using the inline image syntax, since they aren't inline images. There is a pseudo-solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64521414/display-pdf-in-github-markdown), but there's no real clean way to do it otherwise.

Comment: Good catch. I didn't realized that about the PDF file. Changed it to png and it worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. upload your picture or file to github.
2. open that file in github and copy its link.
3. open Readme.md file and type `![Model](Paste_link_here)`
4. enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Before I also used to upload the image to github and gets the url and update it in the `readme.md` file.

But recently in Oct, 2023. I have observed, this approach is not working.

So, I have a way to provide image url to your Readme.md file.

- Create a gist named as images for `<<project name>>` with description as anything, could be your project URL. Example: [`https://gist.github.com/kushalseth/95cfe3df7525cf8bdb14b49bc745a453`](https://gist.github.com/kushalseth/95cfe3df7525cf8bdb14b49bc745a453)
- Now copy the image from your local system and add the image in the comments. Post the Comment. After Posting you can click on image to get the image url. Similar to this: [`https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/10295411/276411958-a070c4cb-c8f0-43f6-8871-675ec035b7af.png`](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/10295411/276411958-a070c4cb-c8f0-43f6-8871-675ec035b7af.png). Check my comments in the above gist url I have provided.
- Now once you got the `gist urls`, add those in your github project readme like this:
  `![testcasesimage](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/10295411/276411958-a070c4cb-c8f0-43f6-8871-675ec035b7af.png)` For Example you can check this github repos readme file: [`https://github.com/kushalseth/swiggy-clone`](https://github.com/kushalseth/swiggy-clone)